# Mathematica, Crossing over two lists

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I was wondering how in Mathematica to start with two lists `f=[1,2,3]` `g=[4,5,6]` and find the list h= f X g which contains all possible pairs `{a,b}` such that `a` is an element of `f` and `b` is an element of `g`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f = {1, 2, 3}; g = {4, 5, 6};
Tuples@{f, g}

(*{{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}}*)
```